# Is it possible to use wine for win32 dll in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, wine

I have fairly large application that has lot of DllImports and works fine under wine. Is it possible to debug same application code base using Visual Studio for Mac by lunching application process under wine?

Comment: Why not use a proper VM instead of an emulation layer like Wine or Parallels?

Comment: VM on dual core mac is very slow, using bootcamp otherwise

Comment: Sounds like Bootcamp is your best bet. If you're debugging something you usually want it running on the target environment, not through emulation.

Comment: Wine is not a Microsoft project, and based on observation Microsoft also shows little interest in it, so I don't think you would be able to do so in VS for Mac.